# Using shift registers with ws2812-b (or c) leds and how to treat the DO signal

Tags: shift-register

Hello  Community Newbie here.

I had a query i would like help  with. I have 8 chains of ws2812c leds (12 leds in each chain)  which I would like to turn into a matrix.
Inorder to do this I was thinking to send each of the DIn at the start of each chain to 74hc595 (pins Q0-Q7 respectivley and each of the led DO at the end of the chains to 744hc165 shift register.

Would this work??
Especially if i wanted to stack each matrix via pin 9 and 14 of the hc74595  and pin 7 an pin 10 of the 74hc165 to create a larger matrix.

I ask as I am struggling to find out how to treat the D0 signal once you get to the end of each chain.

ANY help or direction to resources that might help me would be greatly appreciated .
Power is comming from  7.4V 7400mAh 54Wh battery which will be attenuated to supply the STM32F4 which will supply the SR chips the battery will also supply all the leds approx 3.4 amps drawn;
if all leds are on and at full power.(there will be 672 leds in theproject or 56 chains of 12 leds).
Thankyou in advance for any pearls of wisdom.

Comment: You don't have to do anything with the DO signal. You can use it to extend an LED string to the DI of the next string (effectively extending the string), or you can leave it unconnected. The easiest thing for you to do would be to use the DO of the first string, connect it to the DI of the second string, connect the DO of the second string to the DI of the third string and so forth to create a string of 12 * 8 = 96 LEDs.. No shift registers needed!

Comment: Your last paragraph is unclear. At the start of your question you describe 8 chains. At the end there are 56. Also, 672 LEDs at full power will use **much** more than 3.4A.

Comment: look for the fastLED library ... i think that it has functions for working with an LED grid ... you just zigzag the LED strip to form a 12×8 grid

Comment: ws2812c  current draw is 5 mA according to the data sheet per led. I am intending to create a circuit board which has 8 chains on it. I would like to be able to stack for example 2 or 3 of these boards together to create a larger matrix (zone) or use the boards individually. I have 56 discrete led chains= 672 leds total each chain is going to be associated to an encoder.

Comment: According to the datasheet, that’s 5mA per channel (component LED). Remember each RGB LED consists of 3 individual LED “channels” (one Red, one Green, one Blue). Each of them can draw 5mA. 672 LEDs can draw 672 * 0.005 * 3 = 10.1A.

Comment: wow thankyou ive been reading the datasheet wrong . Also i have just seen a post on adafruit website which suggests using an shiftreg with the adresssable led will require a complete re write of communication code, and of course not to do it.https://forums.adafruit.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=119035

Comment: Have you calculated your data rates and figured what switching rate you can achieve with a given number of LEDs?  I've found a reference to a person doing 1000 LEDs on a single microcontroller at 30fps, but his experience was that not all microcontrollers had enough RAM or processing power, depending on what else you're doing.

Comment: Thank you every one, KH I am using a stm32f407g-disc1 microcontroler max clock in is 168MHz Had'nt even thought about making the calculations. The leds are going to be for visual feed back and not all lit at the same time, the stars of the show are 56 rotary encoders (i am building a midi controler by the way) a 32 key key bed . i will have to do some homework and figure out how to work out achievable switching rates. any hints/ tips on how to do this  would be greatley appreciated.

Comment: HI i have drawn a complete blank as to how i can determine the achievable switching rates i have managed to find formula but this is for switching speed Tsw=CG VDD/Ion not sure if this is right and  there is no indication of what units i should be using. ALSO will fall, reset times, transmission delay (370.3 µs) have a bearing on the calculation along with the i/o  (84kHz) of the MCU. I dont think memory is going to be an issue as leds only  need 2.016 kB 192 kB ( ram available and 1mb of flash available.)